# Check if database exists does not work

Tags: android, database, sqlite, copy, android-sqlite

I have a problem whith my database.
The database is loaded automatically from assets on application start.
It should only be loaded if it does not exist already (first start of application) but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean copyDBFile(Context context)
{
    File dbAbsolutePathFile = new File(dbPath + dbName);
    File dbPathFile = new File(dbPath);

    //Here we make sure that the directory path for the database exists
    if(!dbPathFile.exists()) {
        dbPathFile.mkdirs();

    }



    File dbNameFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);

    //Here we check whether the database file exists or not. If not, we then create it
    if(!dbNameFile.exists()) {
        Log.d("database", "copy");
        //dbNameFile = new File(dbName);
        try {

            //Here we call the copyDB() method.
            copyDB(context.getAssets().open(dbName), new FileOutputStream(dbPath + dbName));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }       
    return true;
}

private static void copyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) {


    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;

    //Here we copy 1K bytes at a time
    try {
        while((length=inputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have empty `catch` blocks?

Comment: what doesn't work? Your application doesn't start at all or your code of check doesn't work?

Comment: They weren't empty a few minutes ago, but the content had problems with static method. I will first need to modify before filling the catch blocks.

Comment: The application will always copy the database from assets and overwrites the existing database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        if(! MyDBHelper.isDatabaseExist(Your_Context , YOUR_DATABASE_NAME))
        new MyDBHelper(this).ImportDatabase(this);
    }
}
public static boolean isDatabaseExist(ContextWrapper context, String dbName)
{
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

For Importing Database

```
public Boolean ImportDatabase(Context c)
    {
        InputStream myInput = null;

        try {


            myInput = c.getAssets().open("Assets/Database.db");


            // Set the output file stream up:


            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();  
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(db.getPath());
            db.close();

            // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            // Close and clear the streams 

            myOutput.flush(); 
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close(); 
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            Log.e("Restoring Database", "file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e("Restoring Database", "IO exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        Log.e("Restoring Database", "Restored");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question (except for the grammatically wrong function name)?

Comment: its depends on context from where it is calling this method. @CL.

Comment: from where this function is called ? @honiahaka10

Comment: In the main activity i call the static function from DBAdapter

Comment: you should call it in MyApplication class. because it will called only once per an installation of application. See my Edited answer. it is currently working for me.@honiahaka10

Comment: With your code i get error that getReadableDatabase(); does not exists. I just implemented your check for the database in a new application class, but it still create a database on every start of Application.

Comment: ImportDatabse should be declare in DBHelper class extends with SQLiteOpenHelper. @honiahaka10

Comment: Now it seems to work. Thank you! I had to modify it a litte, because dbhelper is an inner class of dbadapter:
DBAdapter.DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new
DBAdapter.DatabaseHelper(this);
if(!dbHelper.isDatabaseExist(this , "db.db"))
dbHelper.ImportDatabase(this);

Comment: But the isDatabaseExists() is not necessary because it will alsways return false. (Why?) @Andrain

Comment: No it will only return true if database is exists otherwise it will return false. @honiahaka10

Comment: For me it will return false even if the database exists.

Comment: i dont think so ..!!! are you passing proper value of dbName?

Comment: the name is correct. I make a Log.d() for the result of database exists and it will always return false. When the application is freshly installed (and no database should exist) and when i restart it (so an old database exist).
But if I am trying to start the application in an AVD it will crash with error that it could not  find the database.

Comment: Seems to work now for my phone without making any changes... Oo
But still not working for AVD and I tried it on another phone at it is also crashing there.

How can I post logcat in comments so it is good to read?

Comment: you can post in your question also.